# Kotlin - ClassCastException isn't being caught

Tags: kotlin, classcastexception

Consider the following function

```
fun issueAssetOrThrow(): ResponseEntity<AssetResponseMessage> {
    val response = getOrThrow(controller.issueAsset(ASSET_REQUEST_MESSAGE))

    return try {
        response as ResponseEntity<AssetResponseMessage>
    } catch (classCastException: ClassCastException) {
        val errorResponse = response as ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseMessage>
        fail(errorResponse.body.error)
    }
}
```

In the event of a successful response, `getOrThrow(controller.issueAsset(ASSET_REQUEST_MESSAGE))` will return `ResponseEntity<AssetResponseMessage>`.

In the event of an unsuccessful response it will return `ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseMessage>`, unless there is some catastrophic failure, in which case it throws an exception.

Since the generic part of the response is unknown at this point, the function should first `try` to cast the response to `ResponseEntity<AssetResponseMessage>`.

If it can't perform this cast, it will throw a `ClassCastException` and then tries to cast the response to `ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseMessage>`.

It should then extract the error message and `fail` with this message, throwing an `AssertionError`

The problem is that I actually get this output

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.demo.api.messages.ErrorResponseMessage cannot be cast to
>   com.demo.api.messages.AssetResponseMessage

It looks like `catch(classCastException: ClassCastException)` gets ignored completely! Why is this?

Comment: where do you get this error message? I assume that it is thrown rather in the `getOrThrow`-function...

Comment: The Java runtime discards all generic type information. This means that there won't be any class cast exception in the method that could be catched. Please show us the complete stack trace

Comment: Why do you using `try-catch` block? You can use safe cast `as?` and then just check if it null.

Comment: @Ircover `as?` worked a treat! Add this as a solution and I'll accept.

Comment: are you kidding? How can that be better than `as` itself? are you sure you didn't touch/alter anything else?

Comment: @Roland I refactored the whole thing using `as?`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to lrcover for suggesting `as?` I have now come up with this as a solution

```
private fun <TResult> responseOrFail(response: Any): ResponseEntity<TResult> {
    val errorResponse = response as? ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseMessage>

    if (errorResponse != null) {
        fail(errorResponse.body.error)
    }

    return response as ResponseEntity<TResult>
}
```

Then in my method:

`return responseOrFail(response)`

And now I have the desired result.

Comment: I don't think so... try `responseOrFail` with a `ResponseEntity<AssetResponseMessage>`...

Comment: Try it with any `ResponseEntity<..>`.. it will always call `fail`.. except if you pass anything that isn't a `ResponseEntity`.. then it will give you a `ClassCastException`..

Comment: @Roland it’s only ever called in two cases, one is `ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseMessage>`, the other is `ResponseEntity<TResult>`, and it works!

Comment: What do you mean by "it works"? You tried both `ResponseEntity` and one fails and the other is returned? Or does `fail` just return if error is empty? It just can't be your cast why it works...and if it isn't your cast, you should better adapt your code so that you understand why it works...

Answer (score 1):

Generic type information is erased at runtime. That being said, the following:

```
response as ResponseEntity<AssetResponseMessage>
```

will probably already have shown you a compiler warning (unchecked cast) and is in fact the same as if you write:

```
response as ResponseEntity<*>
```

or to confuse you a bit more another unchecked cast again, which will also work, even if you put an `AssetResponseMessage` inside the `ResponseEntity`:

```
response as ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseMessage>
```

That's also why I asked where that specific error message was thrown exactly. It can not have been thrown inside the `try` and it can not have been thrown inside the `catch`. So the only missing piece is `getOrThrow` itself.

Note also that you may rather want to use `is` and benefit from smart casts instead of casting directly and hoping for a `ClassCastException` (programming against exceptions is an anti-pattern).

Here is a sample:

```
fun getOrThrow(issueAsset : Any /* I don't mind the actual type for now */) = when (issueAsset) {
    is AssetResponseMessage -> TODO("ResponseEntity<AssetResponseMessage> up to you")
    else -> TODO("error? up to you")
}
```

Alternatively you may use the safe cast operator (`as?`). The safe cast operator basically sets a value to `null` in case the cast doesn't succeed, e.g.:

```
 val sample = "test" as? Int
 // now sample has the type Int? and is actually null
```

Note: Casting or safe casting to a class with generic type will not ensure that the object actually contains that generic type, e.g. `someObj as List<Int>` will not ensure that you have actually a list of ints, but rather just ensures that you have a `List` only. Just remember: generic type information is erased at runtime.